# How to copy the last inserted row and paste it in other table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, using `after insert trigger` I am trying to take the last inserted row in table1 , then comparing the row parameters with table2 , and if it is not `exists` in table2 , then take the row and insert it in `table3`.

How can I build this trigger to work ?

In table1 I called the trigger " send_to_3"

```
table1
AFTER
INSERT
```

defenition :

I dont know how to write the code before the "IF"...

```
INSERT INTO 'table3'('ID','name','last_name') VALUES (?,?,?)
IF(new.data = (SELECT data FROM table2 WHERE table2.data <> new.data),1,0)

INSERT 
IF(new.data  = (SELECT data  FROM table2 WHERE table2.data  <> new.data ),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this without an `if`:

```
insert into table3 (id, name, lastname)
    select n.*
    from (select new.id, new.name, new.lastname, new.data) n
    where not exists (select 1
                      from table2 t2
                      where t2.data = n.data
                     );
```

Comment: not working for me , when adding this trigger , the SQL server stoped from getting data in table1. any advice?

Comment: What does "stoped from getting data in `table1`" mean?

Comment: no Entries are stored in table1 from my application  when applying this trigger.

Comment: In that case, `data` is in `table2`.

Comment: ok forget about the "data" lets call it "name" -i will try to explain the issue better: i have 3 tables. table1 handeling the all incoming data, table 2 is the whitelist table, and table3 is the block table... when the entrie is come to table1, i need to do trigger that says, check if "name" fo example apears in table2 if its not there so duplicate the all entire including parameters "name,lastname,id" to table3. so in the end the same entrie must apear in both tables (table1+3).